# How can I choose specific caracters in my "screen_resolution" variable and inspect them separately with an if/else command?

Tags: python

I am doing a system for that the users can choose their screen resolution between 3 
available and write in the console the resolution their chosed ("1920 x 1080", or others) and if they don't put a resolution with the four last numbers that are equal to 1080, 1024 or 900, it automatically puts "Wrong" in the console, my only problem is that it always says the value is wrong, even when I put only the numbers 1080, 1024 or 900.
Did I make a mistake somewhere or is it that it's not possible to do what I want?

For information, I use JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1 x64 (The analyse of my file didn't detect anything) on a Windows 10 64 bits computer.

Code

```py
   screen_resolution = input \
    ("What is you're desired resolution (Choose between the 3 basic resolution: 1920 x 1080 (Native); "
     " 1600 x 1024; 1600 x 900) :")

if screen_resolution[5:] == 1080:
    screen_resolution = "1920 x 1080"
    print("Correct")
    print("The changes will be applied at the next Carventure launch. you chose " + screen_resolution + ".")

elif screen_resolution[4:] == 1024:
    screen_resolution = "1600 x 1024"
    print("Correct")
    print("The changes will be applied at the next Carventure launch. you chose " + screen_resolution + ".")

elif screen_resolution[3:] == 900:
    screen_resolution = "1600 x 900"
    print("Correct")
    print("The changes will be applied at the next Carventure launch. you chose " + screen_resolution + ".")

else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: `screen_resolution == '1080'` etc.

Comment: `w, h = "1600 x 900".split(" x ")`

Comment: `screen_resolution[-4:] == "1080"` - `input()` gives always string  - even if you write digits - so you have to compare with string `"1080"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you very much, what I did is that I've compared it with string `"1080"` (like said furas) and then I changed `if screen_resolution[5:] == 1080:` to `if screen_resolution[-4:] == "1080":`